# ¿Cómo configurar htaccess para prevenir el hotlink de una página php?

Tags: php, apache

Quisiera saber cómo puedo configurar el archivo htaccess para prevenir el acceso directo a una página con extensión php, y que sólo sea accesible al hacer clic en un botón.

Estoy haciendo un formulario de contactos de mi sitio web, pero quisiera que el archivo que contiene las configuraciones de php para el envío (p. j. enviar.php) sea completamente inaccesible mediante su URL directamente desde navegador, que sólo se pueda acceder al dar clic en la opción de Enviar del formulario y no se pueda acceder de ninguna otra forma.

Lo he hecho de la siguiente forma, considerando que, en caso de que se acceda al archivo por hotlink, el servidor devuelva otra página:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)harmonycreativa.tk/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|php)$ http://www.harmonycreativa.tk/error/index.html [R,L]
```

Pero me topé con el problema de que, al intentar enviar un mensaje mediante formulario, en vez de que vaya a la página que le dice al usuario que su mensaje fue enviado exitosamente, se va al redireccionamiento y no ocurre nada. Intenté probar si por la URL se accede al archivo mediante la barra de direcciones, y sigue accediendo, de modo que este código no parezca servir de mucho, a menos que haya algo que esté haciendo mal. :(

También intenté usar este otro código, pero pasó que me restringió el acceso al archivo por completo y ni siquiera al dar intentar enviar un mensaje por el formulario funciona. :(

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)harmonycreativa.tk/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|zip|rar|mp3|flv|swf|xml|php|png|css|pdf)$ - [F]
```

Por lo que quisiera saber si hay una forma de que el archivo enviar.php pueda accederse sólo al dar clic en el botón Enviar del formulario y no de otra manera.

Agradezco de antemano sus respuestas y saludos. :)

Answer (score 0):

para prevenir el acceso a un archivo específico escribe en .htaccess

```
<Files enviar.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
```

Comment: Me sigue enviando a error 403, aun cuando envío el formulario. ¿Alguna sugerencia? Saludos y gracias de antemano por el código.